# How to vectorize double for loop in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, vectorization

i have a code that averages 4 adjacent values into the elements with double loop, i want to vectorize it how can i achieve this ?

```
  for i=2:99
        for j=2:99
        T1(i,j)= (T0(i+1,j) + T0(i-1,j) + T0(i,j+1) + T0(i,j-1))/4;   %adjacent units avarage
        end
  end
```

Comment: A convolution product would work, but do many extra *0 (see https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/393114-implementing-sobel-gradient-without-image-package). There must be better options (an existing gradient function?), but what about widening the matrix by 1 or 2 lines and columns of 0 and summing the 4 shifted copies?

Comment: What you are implementing is the convolution of T0 and '[0,1,0;1,0,1;0,1,0]./4'.  https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a vectorized version of your code:

```
T1(2:end-1, 2:end-1) = (T0(3:end, 2:end-1) + T0(1:end-2, 2:end-1) + T0(2:end-1, 3:end) + T0(2:end-1, 1:end-2))/4;
```

---

Following code sample verifies the vectorized code gives the same result as the loops:

```
T0 = imresize(im2double(imread('cameraman.tif')), [100, 100]); %Read image - used as input for the test.

T1 = T0;
for i=2:99
    for j=2:99
        T1(i,j)= (T0(i+1,j) + T0(i-1,j) + T0(i,j+1) + T0(i,j-1))/4;   %adjacent units avarage
    end
end

T2 = T0;
T2(2:end-1, 2:end-1) = (T0(3:end, 2:end-1) + T0(1:end-2, 2:end-1) + T0(2:end-1, 3:end) + T0(2:end-1, 1:end-2))/4;

disp(['Maximum difference = ', num2str(max(abs(T1(:) - T2(:))))]);
```

---

Using [imfilter](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfilter.html) (or [conv2](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html)):
Your code is equivalent to convolution of `T0` and `[0,1,0;1,0,1;0,1,0]./4` as mentioned by Daniel.
The margins result are different - I replaced the margins with the margins of `T0`.

```
%Filter kernel:
h = [0 1 0
     1 0 1
     0 1 0]/4;

T3 = imfilter(T0, h);

T4 = T0;
T4(2:end-1, 2:end-1) = T3(2:end-1, 2:end-1); %Fix the margins.

disp(['Maximum T4 difference = ', num2str(max(abs(T1(:) - T4(:))))]);
```